# Get rid of [being]

Tags: gerunds

Can "get rid of" be used with gerunds?
▪︎ I'm always forgetting to do what I have to, so I think I need to get rid of [being] so forgettable.

Answer (score 1):

*Get rid of* is only used with nouns, so you would have to say "Get rid of the *habit* of being..." The word you want is *forgetful.* If something is *forgettable*, it is easy to forget about it.